# using xlwt to set borders to the entire excel table

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

Hi!

I'm using Python's xlwt package to make excel documents. What i need is to put a border around every cell in the document (that is between the data).

Let's say i have written in a cell at row 1 column 1. Then i've written in a cell at row 3 column 1. I can easily set borders to these cells at the same time I'm writing stuff into them. But, then, the cell between them, row 2 column 1, doesn't have any borders.

How can this be achieved? I thought i can just write an empty string in these cells that are actually empty, and then put borders around them, but i was hoping for a more elegant solution. Maybe there's a simple method in the xlwt package for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean every cell in the document that is between cells with data?  Or literally every cell, because Excel spreadsheets support a lot of cells.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but using VBA I may define borders to any cell regardless it's empty or not.

Comment: Oh, yes, i meant every cell that is between the data.  I'm editing my original post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Look this samples: http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2011/04/examples-generating-excel-documents-using-pythons-xlwt/

Comment: I've looked at these. It doesn't help me with my problem. It only shows how to put borders around a single cell, which i'm already capable of .

Comment: What do you exactly mean with cells between data? If you have data in A1 and C3 does B2 needs to have borders? What about B3? Or are you only looking at a row at a time and a column at a time or both?

Comment: Yes, B2 should need to have borders.